# What is maxlogins in limits.conf?

Tags: linux

In file /etc/security/limits.conf the maxlogins field refer to what?

If I set

```
 "user1            hard    maxlogins     2"
```

Does this mean "user1" can have two concurrent login at a time or He can login only twice - still the system reboot again?

Comment: this issue ,i found was "logged in as user1 twice" While logging for third time it said "Too many logins"  - So i logged out from previous two logins ...even now it says the same error msg.

Comment: its bug,now fixed - https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=632568 HTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two logins at a time.

Comment: No that's not working...I logged as "user1" in tty1 and tty2 ...while trying to login as user1 in tty3 it says "Too many login" So far good.

Comment: But When i logged out of tty1 and tty2 ...even now it says too many logins

Comment: Then there might something broken in your PAM config.

Comment: Good point,I was messing up /etc/pam.d/login file. thanks,I'll check it

Answer (score 1):

Possibly not, X sessions count as at least one login, as do terminal windows, and I believe shell scripts. In all likelihood, a hard limit of two there is way too few, I would suggest limiting the number of running processess vs the number of logins.

Comment: reproduce steps - (a)who | grep user1 (b) user1 logs into tty1 (c) user1 logs into tty2(d)who | grep user1 (e)user1 log  to tty3 fails (f)logout from tty1 and tty2 (g)who | grep user1 didn't show user1 (h)log into tty3 or tty1 ..it will shortly display "Too many logins".

Comment: I'm not sure why this happens!! Even if i increase session to 5 ...once 5 i login to 5 session as user1 ...after that i can't login evenafter logout from early session.

Comment: Console login =1. Each terminal window opened =1 (you can open as many as you want, regardless of the limit). Each SSH session =1. Once you exceed the MAXLOGINS, SSH will reject new connections. Terminal windows will still open.